# Error - AVPlayer is not playing Audio from remote url - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer

I am trying to play URL audio with `AVPlayer`. When I put a URL with .mp3 extension, it's working fine. but when I used a URL with no extension. it's not worked. Here's [URL](https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&mn=sn-xcvoxoxu-aixe%2Csn-npoeen7k&ip=117.53.42.8&mm=31%2C29&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mt=1547352278&id=o-AIUfw7X-7-vO4ebqBskvYlVvVmhmgp9WJBItzTwZ7c51&keepalive=yes&pl=24&source=youtube&fvip=6&requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&itag=250&gir=yes&clen=4252061&txp=5511222&dur=490.541&lmt=1540081943361780&ei=G7k6XNuzA9TNVv6RjvgI&expire=1547373947&c=WEB&key=yt6&mime=audio%2Fwebm&initcwndbps=143750&signature=774AA79C717B4D9AC6A68743C5730CCBF6A8B9B4.0D91F9D2F80CF12A6623D260B9FC5BB3E69BBAE1&title=Coke-Studio-Season-10-Latthay-Di-Chaadar-Quratulain-Balouch-Farhan-Saeed)

Here's Code.

```
 let url = URL(string: "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&mn=sn-xcvoxoxu-aixe%2Csn-npoeen7k&ip=117.53.42.8&mm=31%2C29&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mt=1547352278&id=o-AIUfw7X-7-vO4ebqBskvYlVvVmhmgp9WJBItzTwZ7c51&keepalive=yes&pl=24&source=youtube&fvip=6&requiressl=yes&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&itag=250&gir=yes&clen=4252061&txp=5511222&dur=490.541&lmt=1540081943361780&ei=G7k6XNuzA9TNVv6RjvgI&expire=1547373947&c=WEB&key=yt6&mime=audio%2Fwebm&initcwndbps=143750&signature=774AA79C717B4D9AC6A68743C5730CCBF6A8B9B4.0D91F9D2F80CF12A6623D260B9FC5BB3E69BBAE1&title=Coke-Studio-Season-10-Latthay-Di-Chaadar-Quratulain-Balouch-Farhan-Saeed")
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    if player?.rate == 0
    {
        player.play()
    } else {
        player.pause()
    }
```

Is there any other way to play audio in iOS with URL's that do not contains .mp3 or any other extension. I don't know why the player is not playing the audio file, there is no sound output on the device and there is no error shown.

Comment: Providing redirecting `url` could be an issue. Try exact `url`. Although your code is completely fine.

Comment: is there any other way to play audio using such a URL?

Comment: You may check this stackoverflow link. You need to specify file type. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501670/2641380

Comment: I suspect the `url` is not a valid. For some reason i couldn't even play on browser(mobile).

Comment: link is fine @Kamran

Comment: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1516408