# While Playing URL with no extension AVURLAsset Fails

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

When i try using `AVURLAsset.init` to an audio having url something similar below . Below url is example url.

https://web-web.test.net/media/abcdefghijklmnopqrst?sr=abcdefghijklmnopqrst

Calling 
 `audioAsset.statusOfValue()` returns as `.failed` . Please let me know if any sugesions.  Below is complete code i have written.

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            audioAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: url)

            if let audioAsset = audioAsset {

                let keys = ["playable"]

                   audioAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {

                    let playableStatus = audioAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: keys[0], error: nil)
                    switch playableStatus {

                    case .unknown,  .loading,  .failed,  .cancelled:
                        return

                    case .loaded:

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(asset: audioAsset)
                            self.audioPlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
                            self.audioPlayer.play()

                            })
                        }
                        break
                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your url is not an url of audio file. You need to pass into `init` exact url of real audio file

Comment: i think you need to setting mime_type with file extension something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501670/how-to-play-movie-files-with-no-file-extension-on-ios-with-mpmovieplayercontroll

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko In above given Url its just a example(Dummy). I cannot share a url in stack overflow reason is its generated from server and expires after 10 minute. I have tried playing url in web it plays without any problem.